# Github `Directory not found` while using reusable workflows

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to use Github reusable workflows.

One workflow would be the reusable workflow to build and test
The caller would then create docker images and push them to registry.

Reusable

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  workflow_call:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'

    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
      with:
        arguments: build
```

Caller:

```
name: Release

on:
  release:
    types:
      - published

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  ci:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci_resusable.yml

  push-images:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: ci

    - name: Get tag name
      id: get_tag_name
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=tag_name::${{ github.ref_name}}"   

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_USER_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_USER_PASSWORD }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
        

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR - stockapp-rest-adapter image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: stockapp-rest-adapter
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.get_tag_name.outputs.tag_name }}
      run: |
        pwd
        cd stockapp-rest-adapter
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

The problem I am having is that when doing `cd stockapp-rest-adapter` I get directory not found, as if the repo is not checked out.

Am I right to assume these jobs are running in the same runner and share the same workspace ?

Any indications on what I may be doing wrong ?

Comment: The reusable workflow doesn't run on the same runner instance as the `push-images` job, therefore the `actions/checkout@v3` needs to be call in this job as well to access the directory.

Comment: @GuiFalourd, So I would need to checkout and build again the project, is there any way of sharing the workspace, so to avoid code duplication ?

Comment: You could use a self-hosted runner, or share the built artifact output between jobs.

Comment: From a quick look a [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) may as well already help, having it in the _push-images_ job as it runs within the same environment. But this is not an option if you plan to have a full re-usable workflow. Albeit it should be straight forward to convert between those two as you go along.

Comment: A composite action would be how you would inline steps to run in the same context as the other steps in the job that invokes the composite action. A called workflow initiates its own jobs in their own contexts. The two options for "reusable steps" in GH are either callable workflows which is a set of other independent jobs, or an action, which contain steps that run _during_ the same job, i.e. all the `uses:` under `push-images:` are calling actions.